# Safely moving objects that run a lambda in a member thread that accesses other members

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, move, swap

I have a class that has an `std::thread` member variable which runs a lambda function that depends on some other member variable.

Let me give an example:

```
struct C {
    C() {
        thread_ = std::thread([this]() {
            running_ = true;
            while (running_) {
                ...
            }
        });
    }
    C(C&& rv) {
        swap(rv);
    }
    void swap(C& rhs) {
        std::swap(thread_, rhs.thread_); // step 1
        std::swap(running_, rhs.running_); // step 2
    }
    std::thread thread_;
    bool running_;
};

int main() {
    C c;
    C c2 = move(c); // Is c safely moved to c2?
}
```

- What is a safe way to move such an object?
- To which object is capture `[this]` going to point after the move operation.
- Which object's `running_` is accessed in the lambda's while loop after `step 1` but before `step 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a `std::thread` is certainly movable, doing so does not magically revise any pointer referring to it, or its containing object, if any.

Thus, even after you move a `C`, the thread managed by the contained `std::thread` will still refer to the objects it referred to before.

So, if you want to safely move/swap a `C`, use the pimpl-idiom:
Only safe a pointer to the resources the thread might access, and give that pointer to it.
In your case, that means:

1. Move `running_`:

   ```
   struct inner {
       std::atomic<bool> running;
   };
   unique_ptr<inner> data_ = new inner;
   ```
2. Pass the pointed-to data:

   ```
   auto data = &*data_;
   thread_ = std::thread([data]() {
       data->running = true;
       while (data->running) {
           ...
       }
   });
   ```

(Optionally also move the data not accessed by the thread.)

Also, even if you didn't ask, your `running` must be a `std::atomic<bool>` so the check works.

Comment: I have doubts even for pimpl-idiom because another thread is being executed in parallel when we go from step 1 to step 2

Comment: I have a hunch that OP will need locking on top of added indirection. Would you agree? @bmm You already have two threads executed in parallel in `C::swap`; pimpl doesn't change that, does it?.

Comment: @user2079303: Locking, perhaps not quite. But `running` must be a `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: @Deduplicator if between steps 1 and 2, the member thread which was swapped from old to new gets to run and dereferences `data`, it will access the `data` of the newly constructed object, won't it? Any changes done would be swapped to the dying object by the step 2. And any value read might be different from the old state which it should have read.

Comment: @user2079303: Corrected a compile-error. The lambda gets a copy of `data`, a raw pointer to the data managed by `data_`. It is blissfully unaware who owns, knows about or doesn't the pointed-to data.

Comment: It is still not clear to me why ``running`` should be ``atomic<bool>`` though. Instead of swapping in 2 steps (step 1 & step 2), we are going to swap the ``inner`` objects in 1 step.

Comment: @bmm `running` should be `std::atomic<bool>` instead of `bool`, to avoid race-conditions in accessing it. If it's a plain bool, it need not even be re-loaded for each check (if not possibly modified in called functions), meaning the `while`-loop effectively devolves to an `if(running) for(;;)`.

Comment: @Deduplicator But if compiler devolves it to ``if(running) for(;;)``, it will not be possible to stop the thread by setting ``running`` to ``false`` from within the lambda function or by calling the C member function, say, ``void C::stop() { data_->running = false; }``. If we suppose that there are no ``running=true`` except the beginning of the lambda function, will the race-condition you warn about be as critical? (I edited the code BTW)

Comment: Let's look at it one-by-one: 1. If `running` will be changed in the loop, the loop-guard will see that. So far, so good. 2. If `running` will be changed by *another thread*, `running` isn't atomic, and you don't synchronize it any other way, the compiler may assume it never changes and optimize accordingly. 2b. Even if it does not, depending on the architecture, the thread testing `running` might never pick up that some other thread changed it without notifying.

Comment: @Deduplicator I did not know these! Which sources can you point me for further reading about the fact that "If I do not use ``std::atomic<bool>``, compiler can devolve it to ``if(running) for(;;)``"?

Comment: The standard (drafts are freely available), semantics of the abstract machine and the as-if rule. Beware though, it's somewhat hard to digest in one sitting.